# Top to bottom text with tikz-dependency for Xibe dependency trees

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex

I'm working on a paper about Xibe, a Tungusic language spoken in China. The language is written in a variant of the Mongolian script, which is written top to bottom.

I've tried using XeLaTeX with `tikz-dependency` with a rotatebox:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-dependency}
\usetikzlibrary{%
    shapes,%
    arrows,%
    positioning,%
    calc,%
    automata%
}
\tikzset{/depgraph/.cd,/depgraph/.search also = {/tikz},
    baseline=-0.6ex, inner sep=-0.1cm, edge horizontal padding=3pt, edge unit distance=1.8ex}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{FreeSerif}
\newfontfamily{\dcw}[Scale=1.5]{Ab-Xy.ttf}%

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\center
 \rotatebox{-90}{%
\begin{dependency}
  \begin{deptext}%[column sep=1mm,column 1/.style={anchor=base west}]
    {\dcw ᡞ}  \& {\dcw ᠰᠣᡢᡤᠣᠷᠣᡢᡤᡝ} \& {\dcw ᠠᠪᠰᡞ }  \& {\dcw ᡠᠰᠠᠴᡠᡣᠠ}  \& {\dcw 。} \\
    \emph{i} \& \emph{songgorongge} \& \emph{absi} \& \emph{usacuka} \& .\\
  \end{deptext}
  \depedge{2}{1}{nsubj}
  \depedge{2}{4}{advmod}
  \depedge{4}{3}{advmod}
  \depedge{4}{5}{punct}
\end{dependency}
}
\caption{Dependency tree for the sentence \emph{I songgorongge absi usacuka.} `He cried so sadly.'}\label{dep:sadly}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Example output here:

[image]

But I'm struggling with being able to make the dependency relations appear horizontal instead of vertical. I think it would be cool to have the option to have the transliteration horizontal instead of vertical too.

Any ideas?

If I add `rotate=90` to each `\depedge` then I get:

[image]

Which isn't quite right because it messes up the arcs. So I'd like to get the arcs like in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slTjR.png) and the labels like in [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qf1Ko.png).

Now, thanks to the answer below, I'm getting [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCHh5.png)

[image]

It would be great to have the Latin transcription go from top to bottom too, e.g.

```
i

s
o
n
g
g
o
r
o
n
g
g
e

a
b
s
i

u
s
a
c
u
k
a
.
```

Comment: You need to add `[label style={rotate=90}]` just after `\begin{dependency}`; or just add `label style={rotate=90}` to your `\tikzset`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can adjust the style of the labels by adding `label style={`...`}` to the `\tikzset` macro. This way, you can rotate just the labels. I removed all unnecessary stuff from the code below and also adjusted the padding of the labels a bit in order to prevent overlapping. (I also changed the Mongolian font, because I only had this one at hand.)

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-dependency}

\tikzset{/depgraph/.cd, edge vertical padding=5pt, edge unit distance=3.5ex, label style={rotate=90}}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{FreeSerif}
\newfontfamily{\dcw}[Scale=1.5]{NotoSansMongolian-Regular.ttf}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \rotatebox{-90}{ 
    \begin{dependency},
      \begin{deptext}
        {\dcw ᡞ}  \& {\dcw ᠰᠣᡢᡤᠣᠷᠣᡢᡤᡝ} \& {\dcw ᠠᠪᠰᡞ }  \& {\dcw ᡠᠰᠠᠴᡠᡣᠠ}  \& {\dcw 。} \\
        \emph{i} \& \emph{songgorongge} \& \emph{absi} \& \emph{usacuka} \& . \\
      \end{deptext}
      \depedge{2}{1}{nsubj}
      \depedge{2}{4}{advmod}
      \depedge{4}{3}{advmod}
      \depedge{4}{5}{punct}
    \end{dependency}
  }
  \caption{Dependency tree for the sentence \emph{I songgorongge absi usacuka.} `He cried so sadly.'}\label{dep:sadly}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

I don’t think that vertical Latin text (with the glyphs upright) is particularly good to read. But, if you really want to have it this way …

There are surely more sophisticated ways to solve this. But for simplicity’s sake, you could use the `stackengine` package. You need to put spaces between all the letters, though …

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-dependency}

\tikzset{/depgraph/.cd, edge vertical padding=5pt, edge unit distance=3.5ex, label style={rotate=90}}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{FreeSerif}
\newfontfamily{\dcw}[Scale=1.5]{NotoSansMongolian-Regular.ttf}

\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackgap{L}{.8em}
\newcommand{\ltn}[1]{\rotatebox{90}{\itshape\Longstack{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \rotatebox{-90}{ 
    \begin{dependency},
      \begin{deptext}
        {\dcw ᡞ}  \& {\dcw ᠰᠣᡢᡤᠣᠷᠣᡢᡤᡝ} \& {\dcw ᠠᠪᠰᡞ }  \& {\dcw ᡠᠰᠠᠴᡠᡣᠠ}  \& {\dcw 。} \\
        \ltn{i} \& \ltn{s o n g g o r o n g g e} \& \ltn{a b s i} \& \ltn{u s a c u k a} \& \ltn{.} \\
      \end{deptext}
      \depedge{2}{1}{nsubj}
      \depedge{2}{4}{advmod}
      \depedge{4}{3}{advmod}
      \depedge{4}{5}{punct}
    \end{dependency}
  }
  \caption{Dependency tree for the sentence \emph{I songgorongge absi usacuka.} `He cried so sadly.'}\label{dep:sadly}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

I’d rather go for the first solution with rotated text though.

Comment: This is beautiful, thanks! Any idea as a bonus on how to get the Latin transcription to go top to bottom? That would be epically cool!